# (jQuery) Show and hide div when expiry date/time is reached

Tags: jquery, date, time, hide, show

```
<div class="info">
TEXT still showing
</div>

<div class="timeout">
TEXT (with display:none)
</div>
```

When 10:00pm 8.Apr
"info" will hide
and
"timeout"s text will show

GMT +1

Many thanks

Comment: What is your question? As it stands, this looks awfully like a "write my code for me" question

Comment: is it using client time or server time? client can easily change their time.

Comment: Reference: [Date documentation at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Reference: [`jquery.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: My answer should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this would work:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

  var current = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date("April 8, 2011 10:00:00")

  if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
      $('#timeout').show();
      $('#info').hide();
  }

}, 5000);
```

I'm not familiar with javascript date functions so I googled this and used a mixture of [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) and [this article](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=221726) to generate this answer

Comment: how can i use server time ? Thanks so much

Comment: Server time for the current date?

Comment: depends on language if your using php then just check out their date function and pass the date in <?php echo "yourvalue"; ?>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to use setInterval to check every second what time it is. Remember it will use client side time. Better way is to use server time to get the duration of elapsed time and set that duration in setInterval to show hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is two things:

- The code to toogle a visibility properties
- To compare the current time and the target time

var targetTime = new Date(2011, 4, 8, 22, 0, 0);//22 means 22:00 ant that is 10 p.m (12 hours few)

var currentTime = new Date();

var targetMilliSeconds = targetTime.getTime();

var currentMilliSeconds = currentTime.getTime();

if ((currentMilliSeconds - targetMilliSeconds) == 0) { /*what ever you want to do*/ }